# css background color won't show

Tags: css, html

I'm a beginner at programming and got this assignment from my teacher, but even tho I do as he told me to, the colors won't show when I open the page.

Basically I'm trying to get a gradient background color, which I've put in the main element, but it doesn't show. It looks like this:

```css
main
/*background-image:url(pics/bg.jpg);    background-repeat:repeat-y; background-color:#FFAA00;*/

#grad {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #FFF, #F80);   /*   For Safari  5.1 to  6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #FFF, #F80);   /*   For Opera   11.1    to  12.0    */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #FFF, #F80);   /* For Firefox 3.6 to  15  */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFF, #F80);   /*   Standard    syntax  */
}
```

But even if I only put like `main {background-color: blue;}`, the background is still white. Would love some help!

Comment: Do you have anything inside that element? My guess is that the element has 0 height. try adding: height: 200px; width: 200px; display: block;

Comment: please provide your HTML & CSS

Comment: Did you want to perhaps post the HTML and CSS in a JSFiddle? This could help us see exactly what is happening, and better help. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Also, you use grad as a selector, grad is not an html element, so you probably want .grad or #grad, depending if it's a class or an id

Comment: @Pete `<main>` is a valid [HTML5 element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element).

Answer (score 0):

works for me, just make sure you correctly name the tags you're styling (and they have height like the others mentioned):

```css
body {
  background-image:url(pics/bg.jpg); 
  background-repeat:repeat-y; 
  background-color:#FFAA00;
}
  
#grad {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #FFF,#F80); 
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
 }
```

```html
<div id="grad"></div>
```